# linker ld cannot find an existing library

Tags: gcc

OpenCV 3.4.10  C++  on Ububtu 18.04 worked fine, yet suddenly the linker started complaining:

```
/usr/bin/ld:  cannot find -lopencv_xxxx
```

though this library is sitting in the same folder together with other openCV libraries used in my code (they all have the same format name libopencv_zzzzz.so and each is there in thre versions .so, .so.3.4 and .so.3.4.10  )

Question: if a shared library is present in the correct folder, does it mean that it is installed?
If it does, perhaps the linker is looking for some other version?
Is there a way to see what exactly linker is looking for?
I tried to run g++ with --verbose. It obviously looks into this folder, but I failed to make out what it was looking for.

Comment: Default is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_[name].so.3.x` https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/amd64/libopencv-contrib3.2/filelist .... If you install opencv-3.4.10 with `sudo make install` your PREFIX may be e.g. /usr/local/lib/. .... → To be found, a library must be in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: thank you.   Opencv-3.4.10 was installed using .sh script downloaded from www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-4-4-on-ubuntu-18-04/ <br/>  
It had a line:   CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$cwd/installation/OpenCV-"$cvVersion" \ <br/> 
On my Ubuntu 18.04 it created /home/a/Downloads/installation/OpenCV-3.4/lib  and placed all  libopencv_zzzzz.so there. <br/>
It used to compile well with <br/>
g++ -L /home/a/Downloads/installation/OpenCV-3.4/lib
<br/>
But recently cannot find certain libraries though the relevant .so files are there in three versions. <br/> I which I knew how to format messages here